# Campus Area Network Deisgn

Tags: network

I have 10 buildings in a campus and I want to design a Network. The design should follow the three layered hierarchical model. Below is my design, I just want to know if the design will work just fine or if needs additional. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: So if one router in the main building goes down, all 10 buildings go down?  You are so fired!  Also +1 on homework. 

Comment: Sorry for the first design, I didn't put any redundancy because I just want to show the basic design. Thanks @DarrellRoot

Comment: Homework problems are off-topic here

Comment: @infra, Im sorry, Im still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider switches in Main Building as Core switches, Distribution and Access Switches have resided in each building. As your topology shows, you have redundancy in your core layer, but you don't have it in the distribution layer (except building A). So if you want to have a stable network with a minimum level of redundancy you need to add at least 3 distribution switches in buildings B, C, D.
On the other hand, the DMZ part is also needed another switch to have redundancy.
Your Internet Edge router is also a single point of failure and you should add another router in order to make your communication outside, stable.

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi for your response, so basically the minimum number of distribution switch per building should be a total of 4?

Comment: No, 2 Distribution switches per building